# springboot jpa repository.save(obj) must not be null, NullPointerException in test

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, junit5, spring-boot-test

I am having issues in writing unit testing for my Kotlin project where my actual usage is working fine. However, my unit testing will throw an unusual error. When I call my save service in my test, it will throw a `java.lang.NullPointerException: movieRepository.save(movie) must not be null`. I am unsure what item that 'must not be null' is referring to as I logged both movieRepository and movie to have some value.

Additional Info: Only when I am adding a new entry, it will throw NPE error. However, when I am performing an update (also uses `.save(movie)`), the test goes through fine. Testing with other functionality such as .findAll() and .deleteById() works fine.

Here are the code snippets:

Movie.kt

```
@Table(name="movie")
@Entity
data class Movie(
  @Id
  @Column(name="id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  val id: Int? = null,

  val name: String,

  val type: String,
)
```

MovieService.kt

```
@Service
class MovieService {
  @Autowired
  private lateinit var movieRepository: MovieRepository;

  fun addMovie(movie: Movie): Movie {
    return movieRepository.save(movie)
  }
}
```

MovieServiceTest.kt

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
internal class MovieServiceTest {

  @Mock
  private lateinit var mockMovieRepository: MovieRepository;

  @InjectMocks
  private lateinit var movieServiceTest: MovieService;

  // Mock Values
  val mockName = "mockName";
  val mockType = "mockType";
  val mockMovie = Movie(name = mockName, type = mockType);

  @Test
  fun addMovie() {
    val result = movieServiceTest.addMovie(mockMovie);

    val movieArgumentCaptor: ArgumentCaptor<Movie> = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Movie::class.java);
    verify(mockMovieRepository).save(movieArgumentCaptor.capture());

    val capturedMovie = movieArgumentCaptor.value;
    verify(mockMovieRepository).save(capturedMovie);

    verify(result.name == mockName)
  }
}
```

Error message

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: movieRepository.save(movie) must not be null

    at com.example.stackoverflow.MovieService.addMovie(MovieService.kt:18)
    at com.example.stackoverflow.MovieServiceTest.addMovie(MovieServiceTest.kt:43)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)


Process finished with exit code 255
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes in your test.

**First mistake:** You have to mock your repository.save method. Kotlin says `"java.lang.NullPointerException: movieRepository.save(movie) must not be null"` because without mocking the movieRepository.save method will return null. Unfortunatly your MovieService.addMovie doesn't return nullable. Hence the nullPointerException.
You can mock repository call this way:

```
Mockito.`when`(mockMovieRepository.save(mockMovie)).thenReturn(mockMovie)
```

**Second mistake:** is in your last assertion `verify(result.name == mockName)`
I guess you wanna assert that result.name equals mockName.You can use junit Assertions for this purpose (https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-assertions)

Mockito.verify is intented to verify certain behavior happened  like a method is call once or several times.

To summarize :

```
    @Test
    fun addMovie() {
        Mockito.`when`(mockMovieRepository.save(mockMovie)).thenReturn(mockMovie)
        val result = movieServiceTest.addMovie(mockMovie);
        
        val movieArgumentCaptor: ArgumentCaptor<Movie> = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Movie::class.java);

        verify(mockMovieRepository).save(movieArgumentCaptor.capture());

        val capturedMovie = movieArgumentCaptor.value;
        verify(mockMovieRepository).save(capturedMovie);
        assertEquals(result.name, mockName)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Realised my mistake as I have been doing `given(mockMovieRepository.findAll()).willReturn(someValue)` but not for .save(). A curious question, is there a preferred way between given().willReturn and when().thenReturn? Or its just the same

Comment: From my point of view these are just different styles. The first is the normal Mockito syntax and the second just tries to fit nicer into BDD  (Behavior Driven Developement) style tests - I really like the second version because it reads so nicely in BDD tests.